# How to read two characters from an input string?

Tags: python, string, input, character, slice

I want my program to read one character from an input of random string, but when there is a space in the string, I want it to read the next two characters.

For example, if I type `H He`, I want it to return the value for `H`, then detect a space then return `He`. How do I do this?

This code is a small part in school assignment (calculating the molecular mass of random compounds).

```
string=input('enter:')

pos=0
start=None

for a in string:
  if a == 'H':
    print(string[start:1])
  elif a == ' ':
    pos=int(string.find(' '))+1
    start=pos
    print(string[start:1])
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code? Can you show an example where the code does not do what you expected?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so that others can see that the problem is solved. If you have another question, please ask a new question instead of editing this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string with space and then get both the values.

```
string=input('enter:')

values = string.split(' ')
if len(values) > 1:
    print("first char:", values[0])
    print("remaining:", values[1])
else:
    print("first char: ", values[0])
```

To split the string without the spaces based on the uppercase letter.

```
import re
elements = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', 'NaCl')
print(elements)
```

Comment: Thank you! that was helpful. Wasn't aware of the split method before. I was wondering if there would there be a way to do the same thing (seperate the two, but without adding any space). For example read 'HHe' as 'H', 'He' or 'NaCl' as 'Na', 'Cl'. Possibly smth to do with the lowercase letter. Sorry this is a bit selfish but I was wondering it it could be done.

Comment: I have edited my answer to split without spaces. Please accept it if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list for the string which you enter and print the list like below:

```py
string=input('enter:')
l=list(string.split())
for i in l:
   print(i)
```

For your new request

```py
string=input('enter: ')
i=0
l=len(string)
while (i<l):
    if(i<l-1):
        if(string[i].isupper() and string[i+1].isupper()):
            print(string[i])
        elif(string[i].isupper() and string[i+1].islower()):
            print('{}{}'.format(string[i],string[i+1]))
    elif(i==l-1 and string[i].isupper()):
        print(string[i])
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Thanks! That was surprisingly easy. Would there be a way to do the same thing (seperate the two, but without adding any space). For example read 'HHe' as 'H', 'He' or 'NaCl' as 'Na', 'Cl'. Maybe smth to do with lowercase letter reading. Sorry this is a bit selfish but I was wondering it it could be done.

Comment: I have added another solution in my answer. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I was wondering if it was possible to do the same thing but separating using lowercase letters?
>
> For example read 'HHe' as 'H', 'He' or 'NaCl' as 'Na', 'Cl' Sorry this is a bit selfish but I was wondering it it could be done

How about this?

```py
import re

words = [
    'HHe',
    'NaCl',
]

pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]*')
for word in words:
    print(pattern.findall(word))
```

output:

```py
['H', 'He']
['Na', 'Cl']
```